# I don't see "Defaults requiretty" in my vsudo file

Tags: debian

I'm trying to disable `requiretty` everywhere (yes, I'm aware it's a security risk, please don't lecture me on that) and am in the vsudo file. However I don't see `Defaults requiretty` anywhere so I can't disable it. Is there a different way to disable it or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The man page says this is off by default

> requiretty
>       If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in to a real tty. When this flag is set, sudo can only be run from a login session and not via other means such as cron(8) or cgi-bin scripts. This flag is **off by default**.

So it should be off. If it's not off and it's not defined in /etc/sudoers, check and see if your version supports #include directives and if so check out the files in the listed directories.